# celery + eventlet = 100% CPU usage

Tags: python, django, celery, eventlet

We are using celery to get flights data from different travel 
agencies, every request takes ~20-30 seconds(most agencies require 
request sequence - authorize, send request, poll for results).

Normal 
celery task looks like this:

```
from eventlet.green import urllib2, time 
def get_results(attr, **kwargs): 
    search, provider, minprice = attr 
    data = XXX # prepared data 
    host = urljoin(MAIN_URL, "RPCService/Flights_SearchStart") 
    req = urllib2.Request(host, data, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'}) 
    try: 
        response_stream = urllib2.urlopen(req) 
    except urllib2.URLError as e: 
        return [search, None] 
    response = response_stream.read() 
    rsp_host = urljoin(MAIN_URL, "RPCService/FlightSearchResults_Get") 
    rsp_req = urllib2.Request(rsp_host, response, {'Content-Type': 
'text/xml'}) 
    ready = False 
    sleeptime = 1 
    rsp_response = '' 
    while not ready: 
        time.sleep(sleeptime) 
        try: 
            rsp_response_stream = urllib2.urlopen(rsp_req) 
        except urllib2.URLError as e: 
            log.error('go2see: results fetch failed for %s IOError %s'% 
(search.id, str(e))) 
        else: 
            rsp_response = rsp_response_stream.read() 
            try: 
                rsp = parseString(rsp_response) 
            except ExpatError as e: 
                return [search, None] 
            else: 
                ready = rsp.getElementsByTagName('SearchResultEx') 
[0].getElementsByTagName('IsReady')[0].firstChild.data 
                ready = (ready == 'true') 
        sleeptime += 1 
        if sleeptime > 10: 
            return [search, None] 
    hash = "%032x" % random.getrandbits(128) 
    open(RESULT_TMP_FOLDER+hash, 'w+').write(rsp_response) 
   # call to parser 
    parse_agent_results.apply_async(queue='parsers', args=[__name__, 
search, provider, hash])
```

This tasks are run in eventlet pool with concurency 300, 
`prefetch_multiplier = 1`, `broker_limit = 300` 
When ~100-200 task are fetched from queue - CPU usage raises up to 100% 
( whole CPU core is used) and task fetching from queue is performed 
with delays.

Could you please point on possible issues - blocking 
operations( eventlet `ALARM DETECTOR` gives no exceptions ), wrong 
architecture or whatever.

Comment: I have been investigating reports about high CPU usage that only happens after upgrading to 2.5.x.  I have not yet been able to reproduce, as I haven't received any example doing so.  But maybe this will do the job, I will try and report back.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A problem occurs if you fire 200 requests to a server, responses could be delayed and therefore urllib.urlopen will hang.

Another thing i noticed: If an URLError is raised, the program stays in the while loop until sleeptime is greater than 10. So an URLError error will let this script sleep for 55 sec (1+2+3.. etc)

Comment: urllib.urlopen - should be a problem - main intention why i used eventlet - was to avoid hangs. second issue you mentioned is not real, it's just due to code simplification before publishing

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late response.

Thing i would try first in such situation is to turn off Eventlet completely in both Celery and your code, use process or OS thread model. 300 threads or even processes is not that much load for OS scheduler (although you may lack memory to run many processes). So i would try it and see if CPU load drops dramatically. If it does not, then problem is in your code and Eventlet can't magically fix it. If it does drop, however, we would need to investigate the issue closer.

If bug still persists, please, report it via any of these ways:

- https://bitbucket.org/which_linden/eventlet/issues/new
- https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet/issues/new
- email to eventletdev@lists.secondlife.com